# Ocultar registros de bases de datos en lugar de eliminarlos

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, java-ee, angular6

Hace poco me surgió la necesidad de hacer un crud de  autos, usando Rest, Java EE, Angular v.6 y la base de datos en SQL server, pero con la diferencia de que en vez de eliminar los registros, éstos sólo estén ocultos del usuario y se mantengan en la base de datos.
Quiero saber si es algo que se puede hacer con SQL o alguna idea para realizarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu tabla de autos puedes agregar una nueva columna boleana el cual indica si esta borrado o no, al consultar, puedes tomar en base a esa columna.

Al eliminar, en lugar de borrarlo de la tabla, cambias el estado de la boleada en falso.